# Current source connected to a transformer

Tags: transformer, ethernet, magnetics

Several communication standards use a line driver which consists of a current source connected to a transformer. ETH is an example in which such current source line driver is used; in this case a parallel 100ohm resistor is used but in other cases no resistors are used and the line driver feeds directly the primary winding of a transformer.

How can a pulse current source induce a voltage on the secondary winding? What about the voltage peaks induced in the primary winding when the current ceases or change signs? They would be huge overvoltages

Comment: Please edit your question including schematic diagrams and links to the example.

Comment: Sounds like LVDS.

Comment: Hint: the secondary of the transformer isn't left open.

Answer (score 1):

The primary "sees" the impedance connected to the secondary (multiplied by the square of the ratio of primary and secondary turns). There will be a bit of leakage inductance because transformers are not perfect but when properly terminated it's essentially resistive to signals in the range that counts (perhaps 100MHz with no DC content in the case of Ethernet).

Ethernet has 100 ohm terminations on each end of the cable, and the cable has a nominal characteristic impedance of 100 ohms. A current source into a 100 ohm resistor is equivalent to a voltage source with 100 ohms in series.